# How to find Raspberry Pi on Network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to the Internet via LAN or via wireless. How do I scan my local network for its IP address so I can SSH into it?

While I can just connect it to a monitor and manually run `ifconfig`, I was hoping there was an easier way like using `nmap`.

Comment: I use [SoftPerfect Network Scanner](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) for this. Depending on your OS, you can probably find a similar tool. Just scan whichever IP range your router / DHCP is assigning and it will show up.

Comment: Here's an nmap solution: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/how-to-find-live-hosts-on-my-network

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [answer on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13937) seems to perfectly nail it. The key is all Raspberry Pi’s have a MAC address that begins with `B8:27:EB` so you can use `nmap` to scan the network and filter for that MAC address like this:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print ip}'
```

Of course the `192.168.1.0/24` should be changed to match your Raspberry Pi’s networking setup, but I assume that `192.168.1.0/24` is the default Raspberry Pi range anyway.

Also, [this page seems to have another nice method](http://serialized.net/2013/04/headless_rpi/) of achieving the same goal by using `arp` and `grep` to find traffic based on only the MAC address; no network range needed:

```
arp -a | grep b8:27:eb | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your on linux, you can try nmap.
You can try something like :

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.0/24  

Nmap scan report for pi (192.168.1.10)  
Host is up (0.023s latency).  
Not shown: 999 closed ports  
PORT   STATE SERVICE  
22/tcp open  ssh
```

This will list all the host on the network 192.168.1.0/24, and list the tcp ports open on each of them. Typically, you'll find your raspberry py has port 22 open, and some other if you have some other services running.